# Laravel: save / attach / sync custom pivot model (belongsToMany)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

hope you're having a good day.

I'm using Laravel 8. I have three models and I need those models "entangled", so to speak.

So, I have three basic tables

```
areas,threats,positions
---
id
name
```

So the relationship needed is something like this:

- Every `t3` belongsToMany `t1` and vice versa. (Many to Many)
- Each `t3.t1` relationship belongsToMany `t2` (Many to  Many)

My approach so far is this:

- For the first relationship I have a belongsToMany realtionship defined on my models (`t3.t1`).
- For the second relationship, I have created a [custom pivot model](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models) for the pivot table, in that model I defined the second many to many relationship (`t3t1.t2`).

So far, the first relationship can be saved by doing `$model->relatedModel()->attach($id);`.

**Now, for the second relationship, how can I attach the related models?**

My last resort is to query the saved custom pivot model and attach the `t2` model(s), but I wanted to ask first if there's a cleaner, *eloquent-laravel* way to do this.

Any advice would help. Thanks in advance for taking your time.

Comment: Can you share the code you have used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**explanation**

the `attach` method is actually a `Model` function. so with your `withPivot` `t3.t1` **is not a model yet**
, when you are accessing with `pivot magic method` from your relation belongs to many  **it only return the column**

**answers**

so for your situation, `withPivot` `t3.t1` pivot as `Model instance`. here the steps

1. create new `PivotModel` that extends `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;`
2. on the your `t1Model`, add `using($classNamespace)` to the `belongsToMany` method, example: `belongsToMany()->using(PivotModel::class)`
3. then when `t1->getT2s->pivot` is already returning `Model instance` and  you can use `attach`  function to that pivot

Answer (score 1):

What I can think is 2 way one is just refer [Spatie Laravel Role permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission)

In Spatie the relationship is like Many-to-many relationship between [Permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/blob/master/src/Models/Permission.php#L51) and [Role](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/blob/dd430b78153e7adc2878e6896cf98a289bb72f48/src/Models/Role.php#L48) and Many-to-Many Polymorphic relationship mapping User, Role and Permission.

**OR**

Using extra attributes in many-to-many pivot relation.

[somethinglike](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->withPivot('column1', 'column2');
```

and attach and detach also accepts [extra attributes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships).

```
$user->roles()->attach($roleId, ['expires' => $expires]);
```

while retrieving you can use where clause to specific your choice

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->wherePivot('approved', 1);
```

I hope this will give you enough idea to implement it. all the snippet are from documentation, so you can directly search and refer

Comment: I actually implemented it with pivot columns like you answer. I was wondering if there could be a more "eloquent" way to do it, maybe the spatie approach is more likely to work. Thank you.

Comment: @Chuy Why you think, this is not eloquent? I would like to understand that, so that I could think about how you want to achieve it?

Comment: @Chuy another question I have is, what is your thoughts on implementing the spate way?

Comment: When I say "eloquent" I mean using a declarative way to extract information (as spatie permissions handles it). Kind regards.

Comment: @Chuy okay, so do you think if you implement spate way, your issue will be resolved? if yes, do you want me to explain that?

Comment: I don't know, I'm gonna try the answer by David Valentino first which is is more similar to what I already had.

Comment: @Chuy okay, try which ever is suitable to you, I am adding reference to Spatie GitHub models, so that you can take reference if required and also you can ask me question if required.

Comment: @Chuy what is the status of your issue, is there anything I can help?